# seekbar with preview, like youtube

Tags: android, youtube, seekbar

I need some component or github link to show a seekbar (or progress bar) of a video, and show a thumbnail of the video at the time set (set by the seekbar)
(like youtube)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I Figured out myself, and I uploaded to:

https://github.com/CorradiSebastian/SeekBarPreview

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sebastiancorradi.seekbar.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Coded By Sebastian Corradi SebastianCorradi@gmail.com"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:textColor="#AAAAAA"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.sebastiancorradi.seekbar.components.SeekBarPreview
        android:id="@+id/seekBarPreviewSDCard"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

.JAVA:

```
public class SeekBarPreview  extends LinearLayout {
    private SeekBar mSeekBar;
    private ImageView mPreview;
    private View rootView;

    private int totalDuration;
    private int currentPosition;
    private MediaMetadataRetriever retriever;

    public SeekBarPreview(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public SeekBarPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public SeekBarPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.seekbarpreview_layout, this, true);

        mPreview = rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mSeekBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

        mPreview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    }

    public void setUrl(String url){
        retriever.setDataSource(url, new HashMap<String, String>());
        String duration = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
        if (duration != null) {
            totalDuration = Integer.valueOf(duration);//milisecs
        } else {
            totalDuration = 0;
            //or throw an exception
        }
    }
    public void setUri(Uri uri){
        retriever.setDataSource(getContext(),uri);
        String duration = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
        if (duration != null) {
            totalDuration = Integer.valueOf(duration);//milisecs
        } else {
            totalDuration = 0;
            //or throw an exception
        }
    }

    public void update(int i) {
        Long newPosition = totalDuration * i * 10L;
        Bitmap bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(newPosition);
        mPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


        int x = mSeekBar.getThumb().getBounds().centerX();
        int newPos = x - (i * mPreview.getWidth() / 100);
        mPreview.setX(newPos);


    }

    public void initialize(){

        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                update(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
        mSeekBar.setProgress(1);
    }
}
```

And in the parent you just have to add, MXL:

```
<com.sebastiancorradi.seekbar.components.SeekBarPreview
    android:id="@+id/seekBarPreviewSDCard"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

JAVA:

```
SeekBarPreview seekBarPreviewSDCard = findViewById(R.id.seekBarPreviewSDCard);

        String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bunny;
        seekBarPreviewSDCard.setUri(Uri.parse(path));

        seekBarPreviewSDCard.initialize();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use this GitHub library for preview images when you seek SeekBar

https://github.com/rubensousa/PreviewSeekBar

Hope this help you...if you need any help you can ask